# Reverse ordering in of legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
library(tidyverse)

n <- 100
df <- data.frame(grp = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "Total"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 value = runif(n = n, min = 1, max = 5),
                 item = sample(c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3"), size = n, replace = TRUE))

df %>% 
  group_by(item, grp) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = item, group = grp, y = mean, fill = grp)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  coord_flip()
```

Does anyone know how I can change the order of the legend so that it corresponds to the order of the bars? (i.e. "Total" should be on top, then A, B, C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_fill_discrete()` function for that.

That is:

```r
library(tidyverse)

n <- 100
df <- data.frame(grp = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "Total"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 value = runif(n = n, min = 1, max = 5),
                 item = sample(c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3"), size = n, replace = TRUE))

df %>% 
  group_by(item, grp) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = item, group = grp, y = mean, fill = grp)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_discrete(limits = c("Total", "A", "B", "C"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of factors using `forcats::fct_relevel`. This way we do not need to set other *grp* item orders:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(item, grp = fct_relevel(grp, "Total")) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, group = grp, y = mean, fill = grp)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scale_fill_discrete` and specify the order of your items you want in the legend by `breaks` argument like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(item, grp) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = item, group = grp, y = mean, fill = grp)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("Total", "A", "B", "C"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>